# how can i open loading before open page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem when you open the page, i need to open loading image before open page, how can i do this

```
    <style>
#dvLoading
{
   background:#000 url(images/ajax-loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
</style> 

$(window).load(function(){
  $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: check this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6F9WT/

Comment: this would be an updated ver. with an acctual ajax loader image http://jsfiddle.net/6F9WT/1/

Comment: @Behnam Esmaili i cannot use onload in body tag , because i use this `Onload="JavaScript:doCallAjax('LIST','1','');"`

Comment: Seems to working for me. check this http://jsfiddle.net/fm8mJ/ . Try this once. Is it working for you?

Comment: @Palash Mondal what is this for ?? `$(document).ready(function() {
    var iSrc = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Us15MaCuNjg/T88jIdQzGUI/AAAAAAAACbE/MDNj13OmjiI/s1600/Demo.jpg";
    var rndNum = Math.random();
    iSrc = iSrc + "?q=" + rndNum;
    $('img').attr('src', iSrc);
});` and its appear under page its not work

Comment: @Palash Mondal its must show laoding pic then open page

Comment: That is just to set the image source, you don't need that part of code. I had added it since I needed to make the page heavy and take some time to load, so that you could see the page loading effect. Hope you got my point...

Comment: @Palash Mondal i do but the image not display , we must display image then the page

Answer (score 0):

`window.load` will wait for the entire contents to load, then fire it. You'd better use 'ready', that is:

```html
<style>
#dvLoading{
   background:#000 url(images/ajax-loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   display: none;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
</style>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#dvLoading').css('display', 'block');
});

$(window).load(function(){
  $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

place the `<div id="dvLoading"></div>` just before the closing `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('#dvLoading').hide();
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fm8mJ/1/)